# jshint reporting variables undefined despite globals property defined in configuration

Tags: gruntjs, jshint

I have a feature-layer application and am writing a jshint gulp task for it.

This is the grunt task:

```
jshint : {
    options : {
        reporter : require("jshint-stylish"),
        force : true
    },
    all : ["Gruntfile.js", "develop/modules/**/*.js", "develop/components/**/*.js"]
},
```

My `.jshintrc` file:

```
{
  "curly" : true,
  "eqeqeq": true,
  "forin" : true,
  "globals" : {
      "angular" : false,  <-- is not defined
      "module" : false,
      "console" : false  <-- Is not defined
  },
  "latedef" : true,
  "maxerr" : 150,
  "undef": true,
  "unused": true,
  "strict": true
}
```

but the output when calling the task on the project is:

```
C:\Users\jason\Desktop\work\QAngular\angular>grunt jshint
Running "jshint:all" (jshint) task

develop/modules/login/login.js
  line 1    col 1   Use the function form of "use strict".
  line 3    col 1   'angular' is not defined.
  line 12   col 13  'console' is not defined.
  line 20   col 21  'angular' is not defined.
  line 21   col 34  'angular' is not defined.
  line 27   col 29  'console' is not defined.
  line 31   col 29  'console' is not defined.
```

According to the documentation, the `globals` setting in `.jshintrc` is supposed to handle this.  Its not.  Are there any possibilities I missed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`grunt-contrib-jshint` does **not** use `.jshintrc` by default, you have to ask for it explicitly by setting `jshint.options.jshintrc` to `true` or a filepath (https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-contrib-jshint#jshintrc):

```
jshint : {
    options : {
        jshintrc: true,
        reporter : require("jshint-stylish"),
        force : true
    },
    all : ["Gruntfile.js", "develop/modules/**/*.js", "develop/components/**/*.js"]
},
```

Comment: I missed the default `null` value for `jshintrc` in the documentation.  Thanks for pointing it out.